# Is jquery append working wrong when using in a loop?

Tags: jquery

I have got this:

```
arr = []
        $(function () {
            for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                arr[i] = $('<h2>Hello</h2>')
                $('body').append(arr)
                console.log(arr)
            }
        })
```

and the result is 4 different (arr) in the console but just 4 x "Hello" on the screen.
Anyone know why?

Comment: What do you expect to happen instead? Why are you appending an array of headers?

Comment: What result do you want to get?

Comment: I just made a simple example for easy understanding. @user4642212
If logical, the result should be (arr[1xHello] + arr[2xHello] + arr[3xHello] + arr[4xHello]) append one by one to body.
It means 10xHello on the screen.
Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```js
var arr = [];
for(x = 0; x < 4; x++) {
    var h2 = $('<h2>Hello</h2>');
    arr.push(h2);
    $('body').append(arr);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```